# Check how long function is currently running Python

Tags: python, time

So lets say I have the function:

```py
def f(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print(i**2)
    return x
```

I want to implement this:

```py
print(f(99999999))

if f.runTime() > 0.1:
    #DoSomething()
```

So it will call the function, but will DoSomething() if f() is taking longer than 0.1s (even before f() returns!)

So no, the `time` module is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You’ll have to use threads - good luck!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html

Comment: @barny figured as much. Exactly what I wanted to avoid because it'll be a mess.

Comment: If you are using Python professionally, you'll need to have threads under your belt at some point.  Now seems like a good time.

Comment: Try using `timeout_decorator` which could be useful. https://pypi.org/project/timeout-decorator/

Answer (score 2):

As some people suggested, **the good option** here is using threads, you can check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) or this [example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Threading).

If you don't want to get in there and your time checking must not be very precise, you can do like this:

```
import time
def f(x):
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(x):
        if time.time() - start_time < TIME_LIMIT:
            print(i**2)
        else:
            raise Exception('execution time exceded')
    return x

try:
   print(f(99999999))
except Exception as error:
   print(error)
```

this is a worse solution because it will lose some execution time while checking in each iteration, but you can try if this works for you.

Comment: User has already mentioned he's not looking for `time` module.

Comment: @Jarvis, as I understood, OP doesn't need the `time` module itself, but this is not just the time module